# How to fix unallocated shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

now stuck at 75.2%
curl -XGET -u elastic:changeme  'localhost:9200/_cat/health?pretty'
1484915420 12:30:20 elasticsearch red 5 5 5656 2828 0 0 1870 0 - 75.2%

I can't fix it - tried to restore many times - gets up to 67.2%
what do we do?  restore from many days back?
this shows many unallocated shards curl -XGET  'localhost:9200/_cat/shards?pretty' -u elastic:

Comment: Are any shards "in motion" - "initializing" - or does it just seem to stop?

Comment: Which version of ES you are using?

Comment: @Alain collins No, No shards are initializing showing as Unassigned

Comment: In ES2, I would sometimes have to "kick" a few shards manually before it would start assigning all of the others.  See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-reroute.html

Comment: "the shard cannot be assigned because allocation deciders return a NO decision.
primary shard for this replica is not yet active

unassigned:
Reason: "cluster recovered"